# Position absolute not scrolling on devices or Down Position of Links

Tags: html, css

My [site](http://gshare-test.elasticbeanstalk.com/mobile/#/monitoring) has problem in its menu. It isn't completely visible or scroll on mobile. I'm attaching picture [image]

I have position:absolute on drop down menu. Can i make this home menu scrollable with rest of page or any other css fluid positioning to make Admin and Logout link down for all device and desktop at bottom? Thank you.

Comment: just u need the scroll? or the menu need to occupy the full height?

Comment: @vasanthI would like to have menu occupy the full height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
.log-down,.admin-down {  top: 0;}
}
```

do the same thing that Vasanth did but instead of doing the position absolute do

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .log-down,.admin-down {
        position:fixed
        bottom: 0px;
       }
    }
```

e.g.

```
  bottom:0px; = bottom of the page
    top:0px; =  top of the page
    position:fixed = move with the screen
```

I hope i helped or i just misunderstood your question

Answer (score 0):

Add this css and check out

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .log-down,.admin-down {  
       top: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: But it just go close to home. Can they not stay at bottom?